# Recent diamond activity on MSU

Tags: support, meta

For the past 3 weeks or so, diamond activity on Meta has been on a long time high. Even team members partipate. And it's not just recent topics, but also older ones being replied to and statuses assigned.

What's going on here? Early spring cleaning? Coincidence? Is this a burst of activity, or do you intend to keep this up?

Comment: Btw, I like it. Meta sometimes is pretty deserted, with no activity by anyone who looks official, features and bugs ignored etc... Please continue giving some attention to this meta.

Comment: Cinincidence? Or Coincidence?

Comment: @sathya thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the contrary, there's been more user activity on meta lately, which leads to us being on meta more because there's stuff to respond to.

Site mods automatically get an inbox notification when there's a meta post. When users start posting a whole bunch on meta, we see those notifications, and in turn respond.

I'm not aware of any conscious effort to spend more time on meta - it just happens that there's been more activity from our involved users, so we're responding to that.

Comment: It's more than site mods. Jeff is more active, and several other diamonds that aren't SU moderators. And it's not just current topic either, but digging up really old topics. Check out some of the topics on the front page when they were originally posted...

Comment: Jeff is known to dredge through stuff on MSO and re-tag, edit, or even delete things that don't seem useful any longer. My guess is he's just doing it here too. Meta sites tend to get like beaches littered with so much driftwood you can hardly see the sand if a periodic 'spring cleaning' doesn't happen.